# Is there any GENERAL symmetry behind holography and dualities?

Tags: holographic-principle, duality

Holography tells that a theory with gravity in D-dimensions is equivalent to a field theory in D-1 on the boundary. Similarly, after the second string revolution, we know there are symmetries called dualities, pervading every superstring or M-theory. What is the symmetry principle and/or general invariance under these maps? And moreover, what would be the conserved quantity or Noether identity associated to these?
Addendum: in classical mechanics, when you pass from a sistem with N d.o.f., to N-1 d.o.f. you get a momentum conservation from cyclic coordinate. What is the cyclic "coordinate" under a holography or duality map? If any...I mean, is there any known consequence after dimensional reduction. Of course, I suppose the trick is in the counting of the fields.

Comment: This is actually a deep question but it may still be too deep for the present day. You can see preliminary ideas like https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.02500

Comment: Noether's theorem relates *continuous symmetries* to conserved currents. Dualities are non-trivial alternate descriptions of a theory. They are not continuous and they are not symmetries in the sense of Noether's theorem

Comment: Electromagnetic duality DOES have conservation laws related to zilches and helicity...Perhaps we should enlarge our notion of symmetry to include dualities somehow...

Comment: @riemannium, In that case the duality is a map between field configurations of the same theory (so it can be thought of as a symmetry), and it can be extended to a continuous symmetry. By the way, I don't see your comment unless you link me with @

Comment: @octonion How do you extend em duality to a continuous symmetry? I only know how to extend to $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$, which is discrete.

Comment: @RyanThorngren, You can act on the vector $(E,H)$ by a rotation matrix to continuously interpolate to $(H,-E)$. This is just an ordinary classical symmetry of Maxwell's equations, and corresponds to a conservation of helicity. Hardly a `duality' of the type OP wants to consider